# Conversion of .mm files to .m file in iphone

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4, ios5

Can we convert .mm file to .m file? Any links for it? Also can we convert .cpp files to .m file?
Thanks 
Rakesh

Comment: What do you mean 'convert' - they are all text files, just rename them? (.cpp to .m probably isn't what you want to do though!). What are you trying to do?

Comment: sorry changing .cpp to .m will give a lots of errors I have got a code in .cpp files i want to change it to .m code

Comment: Depending on what you mean, the answer is either Yes, or No: Yes, it is in principle possible to convert between Objective-C, Objective-C++ and C++, as they are all turing complete, but No, it is not possible to write a `.m` file which will be exactly equivalent to an arbitrary `.cpp` file, because C++ and Objective-C are different languages, with a different structure and different semantics.

Comment: Why do you want to change them; Xcode will compile them all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**.cpp** to **.m** is a No, however, **.mm** to **.m** Yes.

There is no "converting" the files though, just rename the file extension.

Be careful though that you do not have C code in the **.mm** file because it will not compile in a **.m** file.

Comment: so what to do solve the errors which will generate when renaming the .mm to .m Any way thanks for the tip WrightsCS it gave me more knowledge on the topic

Comment: **.m** files do not support C based code, so there is nothing you can do if you have a C based code in that file other than to remove that code.